# C Function to retrieve argv contents to string

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, argv, argc

I'm not going to have the time to submit my solution any way, yet I'm so frustrated.

I am coding a function that would take `argv` on execution and concat its contents in a string with commands separated by `\n`
Something like this `"./a.out \n a \n b \n c \n ..etc"`.

Here's m code ( and it doesn't work):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *my_concat_params(int argc, char **argv){
    char argss[argc];
    
    for (int i = 0; i<argc;i++){
        strcpy(argss[i], argv[i]);
    }
        return argss[0];
    }


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //char *cmdlne = my_concat_params(argc , argv);
    printf("%d, %s\n", argc, argv[argc-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

What's the proper way to navigate through the pointing to pinter and getting back a string of what i want?

Comment: your argss is on the function stack, returning it is indefined behaviour

Comment: You cannot use stack variables after the function returns, so you need to allocate a buffer on the heap.

Comment: Also, `strcpy` requires each arg to be a `char *`. You are passing it a `char` for the first arg. And for concatenation, `strcat` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You have two options. Declare the output array `char argss[1000];` in `main`, and pass it to the function as a third argument. `malloc` memory for the array `char *argss = malloc(1000);` and return the pointer from the function `return argss;`

Answer (score 2):

`argss` is on the stack so you can't return it.

You want a `char *` that uses `realloc` to increase the length.

Here's some code [for clarity, I used `|` as the separator instead of `\n`]:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void *
xrealloc(void *buf,size_t len)
{

    buf = realloc(buf,len);

    if (buf == NULL) {
        perror("realloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    return buf;
}

// RETURNS: pointer to concatenated string
char *
my_concat_params(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *buf = NULL;
    int dstlen = 0;
    char *src;
    int srclen;
    int seplen = 0;

    // process all arguments
    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        // point to current argument
        src = *argv;

        // get its length
        srclen = strlen(src);

        // grow the output buffer:
        // output length + space for separator + arg length + space for EOS
        buf = xrealloc(buf,dstlen + seplen + srclen + 1);

        // add the separator [for _subsequent_ arguments]
        if (seplen)
            buf[dstlen++] = '|';
        seplen = 1;

        // append the current argument
        strcpy(&buf[dstlen],src);

        // increase output length to account for current argument
        dstlen += srclen;
    }

    // add EOS string terminator
    buf[dstlen] = 0;

    return buf;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *cmdlne = my_concat_params(argc,argv);

    //printf("%d, %s\n", argc, argv[argc - 1]);
    printf("%s\n",cmdlne);

    free(cmdlne);

    return 0;
}
```

---

For the invocation:

```
./fix1 abc def hello world
```

The output is:

```
./fix1|abc|def|hello|world
```

Comment: @OznOg For brevity/clarity, for something so simple, I often omit the check as I consider it assumed unless it's a crucial part of the problem, however just to keep the peace ...

Comment: Yes I can understand, but this needs to be said so that "copy/paste" programming can be warned... (BTW, the leak is still there even with your edit, the exit saves it all)

Comment: what happens if realloc() returns NULL?  You not only leak, but since you lose the original pointer, you lose all possibility of recovery. Please use proper form when posting answers.  Some of us have to deal with these 'mistakes' on a daily basis, and it's not fun.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy There is little "recovery" to be done other than to abort. If you run out of memory here [which you probably won't], aborting is the _correct_ action to take. I'm aware of the `tmp = realloc(ptr,...);` idiom but I don't agree with it. What do you mean by "proper form"? And, since I added `xrealloc`, there is a "leak" but who cares since we're terminating immediately?

Comment: I would care, and you would not pass cocde review.  I'm not the only one.  By freeing the memory when you've ran out, you can at least attempt do a bit more than have the system print a SEGFAULT.

Comment: Oh, please ... In 50 years, I've passed many code reviews, including mission critical code for satellite uplinks. It is a _fallacy_ to assume that you can do "recovery" after running out of memory for mission critical apps. If you design the program so that you _can_ run out of memory, it's a misdesign to begin with (realtime safe programs don't allow allocation except during initialization). So, what [specific] _meaningful_ recovery would you do for this program here?

Comment: .... or having a piece of machinery bump into someone.  You never know what the OP is working on.  Keeping proper form is not a bad habit, and teaching it is good karma.  Sorry for being retentive about it, but I've been programming for about that long as well, I know you've also lost a lot of time dealing with obscure bugs due to code that was initially written with the 'who cares' mentality in mind.  When a newbiie asks for tips, showing tham the right way by adding two lines of code is the right way to help, and everyone who will be working with them for the years to come.  Nothing personal

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return stack allocated space from a function.  Doing so will lead to unintended results, of which an immediate crash is possibly the best outcome.

Your best course of action is to dynamically allocate memory on the heap to store you result.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef MCCP_MIN_GROW_BY
# error "The name MCCP_MIN_GROW_BY already used, pick a different name"
#endif
#define MCCP_MIN_GROW_BY (128) // pick a value that matches best your expected input 
                               // and available resources.

char *my_concat_params(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    int available_bytes = 0;
    int next_length     = 0;
    int allocated_bytes = 0;
    int bytes_to_add    = 0;

    char* result        = NULL;
    char* current_pos   = NULL;
    char* temp          = NULL;

    result = (char*)malloc(MCCP_MIN_GROW_BY);
    if (!result)
       return NULL;

    *result = 0;   // takes care of the case argc == 0

    current_pos = result;
    available_bytes = MCCP_MIN_GROW_BY;

    while (argc--) 
    {
        // append the next argument to the result, allocating space as needed.
        next_length = strlen(*argv);

        if (available_bytes < next_length + 2)  // '\n' + '\0'
        {
            bytes_to_add = ((next_length + 2) < MCCP_MIN_GROW_BY) 
                             ? MCCP_MIN_GROW_BY
                             : next_length + 2;
            
            // when using realloc, do not lose your original pointer
            // so you can at least free resources gracefully in case 
            // of an error.
            temp = (char*)realloc(result, allocated_bytes + bytes_to_add);
            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                free(result);
                return NULL;
            }
            available_bytes += bytes_to_add;
        }

        memcpy(current_pos, *argv, next_length);  // add the string
        current_pos += next_length;

        *current_pos++  = '\n';                    // the line feed
        *current_pos    = 0;                       // and terminate
        available_bytes -= next_length + 1;        // keep track of space left
        ++argv;
    }
    return result;
}
#undef MCCP_MIN_GROW_BY


int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    char *cmdlne = my_concat_params(argc, argv);

    printf("%d, %s\n", argc, cmdlne);

    free(cmdlne);

    return 0;
}
```